# Migrate As2 AS3 attachMovie() conversion

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript-2

Can anyone advise me how to convert it to AS3?

```
_mc.attachMovie("_mc1", "_mc2_" + _item, _mc.getNextHighestDepth());
```

_item is a random number that comes from a previous function.

```
ex: _mc2_ + _item  => _mc2_0, or _mc2_1 etc
```

and must return me the

```
_mc["_mc2_" + _item]
```

regards!

Answer (score 0):

Using `attachMovie` as you are doing is replaced by a few things:

- To create a display object, use the [`new` operator](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#new), like any other object.
- To reference a library symbol item by "linkage id" as you are doing with the first argument `"_mc1"` you can simply use the symbol's linked class name you assigned in the library properties, ex `new MySymbol()`.
- To add the display object to the display list, use [`addChild()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#addChild()). Usage of `getNextHighestDepth()` is obsolete in AS3 because depths are not sparsely/arbitrarily populated, and `addChild` always places the display object on the top of the list.
- To give a display object a name, assign a value to the [`name` property](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#name).
- To get a reference to a display object by name, as you are doing with `_mc["_mc2_" + _item]` you must use [`getChildByName()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildByName()).

Putting this all together it might look like this:

```
var mc:MovieClip = new MyLibrarySymbol() as MovieClip;
mc.name = "_mc2_" + _item;
_mc.addChild(mc);

_mc.getChildByName("_mc2_" + _item);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Very helpful!  Regards!